Let $x=\phi(t) $，If $\phi(t)$ is derivable and $\phi '(t) \neq 0$, can we determine if x has an inverse function?
Let $x=\phi(t) $，If $\phi(t)$ is differentiable and $\phi '(t) \neq 0$, can we determine if x has an inverse function?
I know that if a function is differentiable everywhere, then it is continuous everywhere, but the derivative is not necessarily continuous. For example:
$$
y=
\begin{cases}
x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} & ,x \neq 0 \\\ 
0     & ,x = 0 
\end{cases}
$$
Here, the derivative when $x\neq 0$ is $y'=2x\sin \frac{1}{x} - \cos \frac{1}{x}$;and when $x=0$, $y'=0$ The limit at $x=0$ does not exist, so it is not continuous.
So, is there a function whose derivative can change from positive to negative without passing through zero, such that the function is continuous, but it cannot be inferred that it is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing within an interval, and thus may not have an inverse function?
Or is there a theorem that states: If a function is differentiable everywhere, and its derivative is non-zero, the derivative must be either always positive or always negative, thus making the original function strictly increasing or strictly decreasing?
I think the second statement is correct because if a function is differentiable everywhere, then it should be smooth and continuous. If the derivative changes from positive to negative, or from negative to positive, then the original function must have an extremum at that point, and the derivative at that point must be zero. Is my understanding correct?

What you’re searching for is Darboux’s theorem, and you are right.

Yes, there is a theorem called Darboux' theorem which states

Let $I$ be a closed interval, $f\colon I\to \mathbb {R}$ be a differentiable function. Then $f^\prime$ has the intermediate value property: If $a$ and $b$ are in $I$ such that $a<b$, then then for every $z$ with $f^\prime(a)<z<f^\prime(b)$, there is $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f^\prime(c)=z$.

Your claim follows by taking $a$ and $b$ such that $f^\prime(a)<0$ and $0<f^\prime(b)$, then by taking $z=0$ and appealing to this theorem.
Hope this helps. :)
